# How to use Dlookup for 1 field in Tab Control of Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Still working with Access 365, I have 4 Tables and 1 form

```
Table Plant {PID(key), Name}；  
Table Provider {VID(key), Company}； 
Table Contractor {CID(key), Plant, Provider}；  
Table KPI {KID(key), ServiceID, KPI1, KPI2}.
```

Their relationship:

```
Plant.PID = Contractor.Plant,  
Provider.PID = Contractor.Provider,
Contractor.CID= KPI.ServiceID
```

Form KPI bound with Table KPI, to simplify the way to input data, I created a tab control "TabCtl64" with 2 pages - "KPI" and "Detail". In page "KPI", there are combobox "cbxPlantID", combobox "cbxProviderID" and a text field "ServiceID". What I want: when user choose the plant from "cbxPlantID" and the Provider from "cbxProviderID", it will lookup CID from table Contractor then retrieve the value into field "ServiceID".

I tried like this :

```
Private Sub cbxProviderID_AfterUpdate()
ServiceID = DLookup("[CID]", "Contractor", "[Plant]= " & [Forms]![KPI]![cbxPlantID] & " And [Provider] =" & [Forms]![KPI]![cbxProviderID])
End Sub
```

Then error shows: can't find a record in the table Contractor with key matching field ServiceID. But there is the record.
And I created another form without Tab Control, same code can work - so I guess the problem may be linked with naming conversion in Dlookup of comboboxes cbxPlantID and cbxProviderID: [Forms]![KPI]![cbxPlantID] is not correct for a field in Tab control of form. But I can't find how to correct.
Does anyone know it?

Comment: A tab control is irrelevant when referencing controls placed directly on pages and not in subform. Same code should work. Something else is wrong when using tab control. Instead of DLookup, include CID as column in combobox and code can reference column to grab value. Are these comboboxes cascading - is Provider list restricted by Plant choice or vice versa?

Comment: I didn't use combo boxes cascading  for choosing provider& plant yet. when I tested, just choose those have the record in Table Contractor.